# Por que algumas perguntas são listadas com um fundo bege

Tags: suporte

Sério eu ainda não entendi, primeiro achei que eram as perguntas que eu já tinha lido, depois achei que era as perguntas que não li, depois achei que eram as que tinham/ñ tinham respostas ou resposta aceita/ñ aceita, agora a única coisa que sei é que nada sei a respeito disso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: no meta isso não acontece, todas as perguntas ficam com fundo branco.

Comment: Explica melhor isso. Estás a falar do que?

Comment: São as perguntas com as tags favoritas dele. O oposto disso: [O que significa essas perguntas que estão aparecendo “semi transparente”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1219/3117)

Comment: Ah não conhecia essa das tags ignoradas...

Comment: Isso é bege?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @JorgeB. achei parecido com bege fui lá google e digitei "cor bege" ficou parecido...rsrsr

Comment: ahahahahah fiz o mesmo agora para confirmar :D

Comment: Eu diria amarelado :D

Comment: @Math está esperando o que para responder? :P

Comment: quase da p/ abrir outra pergunta qual é o nome dessa cor..rsrsr

Comment: @JorgeB. tava pensando se não é duplicada, pois a resposta na verdade cita todas as possibilidades. Normal; Favorita; e Ignorada. O que acham?

Comment: @Math eu pus para fechar como duplicata, mas depois tirei, porque lá a pergunta é outra e pode confundir. Não sei...

Comment: então lá no link http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219/o-que-significa-essas-perguntas-que-est%C3%A3o-aparecendo-semi-transparente diz um pouco sobre isso, mas eu pesquisei de outra forma então não achei

Comment: @MaisonSakamoto por isso perguntas duplicadas (quando criadas de forma orgânica) são benéficas para o site. Eu votei a favor da sua pergunta e ao mesmo tempo votei para fechar. Eu até pensei em responder sua pergunta mas eu não tenho nada a acrescentar que já não tenha sido dito pelo mgibsonbr no outro tópico, e a imagem que ele montou está muito boa, então o ideal na minha opinião é redirecionar quem chegar nessa questão aqui para a de lá.

Comment: sim entendi @Math seu comentário seria a minha resposta, mas como já tinha outro link que de certa forma já responde, então cliquei em aceitar o link como resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Para mim isso é cor-de-rosa...