# O que significa quando uma pergunta está com fundo amarelo?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Às vezes eu vejo algumas perguntas que tem uma cor *amarelinha*, diferente das perguntas normais que são brancas:

[image: Print]

O que significa essa cor mais *amarelinha* nas perguntas?

Comment: Nao posso ver o print, tem link dessa pergunta?

Comment: Se for na página principal, é porque esta pergunta possui uma tag que você marcou como favorita no perfil

Comment: Tá ruim em @Articuno, tá tudo bloqueado ai. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ywnu.png

Comment: Vejo tudo branco haha, se não me engano são perguntas que contem suas tags favoritas.

Comment: Eu vejo levemente uma cor mais *amarelinha* @rray

Comment: É na página principal @Articuno

Comment: no canto esquerdo tem a lista de tags favoritas que você marcou, se ela tiver uma dessas tags, irá destacar em amarelo do restante.

Comment: Não é no direito @Articuno? =) Entendi

Comment: Depende do ponto de referencia :p Mas é canto direito mesmo.

Comment: Não é bem uma duplicata @Math, ao meu ponto de vista. Eu tinha lido esse post que você marcou, mas resolvi fazer aqui para deixar mais claro.

Comment: Bom, a pergunta do outro post não é a msm que a sua, mas a resposta responde a outra pergunta e mais a sua, que é o mesmo caso dessa daqui: [Por que algumas perguntas são listadas com um fundo bege](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2659/3117)

Comment: Acho que vale deixar pois está com outro título né @Math? Deve ajudar a encontrar mais facilmente.

Comment: Ah sim, com ctz, pode deixar ;)